# Binding custom property updates to the datasource abnormally?

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, datagridview

At first, I want to talk a little about normal binding (with standard property such as Text of a textbox). The sample grid here has only 2 rows (for simplicity). Suppose I have a table of 2 rows (myDataTable) with 2 columns (ID and Name), a DataGridView (myGrid) and a TextBox (myTextBox). Here is the code for binding data:

```
myGrid.DataSource = myDataTable;
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "Name");
```

After binding data, when the selection changes in the grid, the info is updated automatically to the control TextBox, for example, the 2 rows are:

```
ID       |       Name
1                .NET
2                Java
```

At first, the selection in grid is at index 0, the Text of myTextBox is ".NET", moving the selection to next position (at index 1), the Text of myTextBox is "Java", moving again and again, forward and backward, it works OK as I expect. But now I have a control with a custom property called List, this is type of List and is readonly. I want to bind it to a column of table (for example, Name), I do the same binding rule, however add a little custom Parse to format the correct string before updating to the datasource (myDataTable) because my custom property is type of List while my Name column is type of string, here is the binding code:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("List", myDataTable, "Name"){
   ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never //Because my List property is readonly
};
//formating string data before updating to the datasource
bind.Parse += (s,e) => {
  List<string> data = (List<string>) e.Value;
  if(data.Count == 0) e.Value = DBNull.Value;
  else e.Value = string.Join(",",data.ToArray());//format as comma separated string
};
myCustomControl.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

In this case, suppose myDataTable currently has no data at column Name like this:

```
ID      |      Name
1           <DBNull.Value>   <--- current index
2           <DBNull.Value>
```

After running the demo, the current selection index in the grid is 0, I try changing the value of myCustomControl property List (the Items, not the reference), for example, update it like this:

```
myCustomControl.List.Add(".NET");
myCustomControl.List.Add("Java");
```

Then, moving the selection in grid to the next position (index 1), the value ".NET,Java" is updated to the datasource in row 0 at column Name, like this:

```
ID      |      Name
1             .NET,Java
2                             <----- current index
```

Now if I move the selection back to index 0, the value at column Name in row 1 is also updated to ".NET,Java" like this:

```
ID      |      Name
1             .NET,Java     <----- current index
2             .NET,Java
```

Which is not what I want. I mean the value should be updated via control myCustomControl. Here is what I want:

```
ID      |      Name
1             .NET,Java     <----- current index
2
```

I  can understand that, at the time moving back from index 1 to index 0, the value of List property is still a List with 2 items (".NET" and "Java") and so after the moving, this is updated to the cell at column Name in row 1. I'm finding how to reset that value of List property after it's updated to the cell at column Name in row 0 so that when the selection is at index 1, it's already empty. I'v tried changing the Parse event handler to the following but no good shake:

```
bind.Parse += (s,e) => {
  List<string> data = (List<string>) e.Value;
  if(data.Count == 0) e.Value = DBNull.Value;
  else e.Value = string.Join(",",data.ToArray());//format as comma separated string
  //I think at here, the value has been already updated to the datasource
  //and I can perform the reset
  myCustomControl.List.Clear();
};
```

But it seems to Clear before the value is updated to the datasource and so there is no value udpated to the datasource (instead of ".NET,Java", it's a DBNull.Value).

Then I have also tried this:

```
bind.BindingComplete += (s,e) => {
   if(e.BindingCompleteContext == BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate)
      myCustomControl.List.Clear();
};
```

I thought, it should check if the data is updated to the datasource, the List can be clear. I have also tried some flag to mark as true before clearing and reset it to false after clearing, use this flag to control the flowing in bind.Parse but it did nothing.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem? Your help would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution myself. In fact I can't reset the List anyway, this will update the underlying datasource when switching between rows in the grid. The key idea here is initially set DataSourceUpdateMode to DataSourceUpdateMode.Never, then whenever the List is about to change, turn the DataSourceUpdateMode to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged. In the Parse event handler, after the parsing is done, reset DataSourceUpdateMode to DataSourceUpdateMode.Never. And that works greatly. The underlying datasource is updated only when user changing the control's value (List) by typing or selecting ,...

Here is all the code:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("List", myDataTable, "Name"){
  ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never, //Because my List property is readonly
  DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never//This will be turned on when preparing to change the List's value
};
//formating string data before updating to the datasource
bind.Parse += (s,e) => {
  List<string> data = (List<string>) e.Value;
  if(data.Count == 0) e.Value = DBNull.Value;
  else e.Value = string.Join(",",data.ToArray());//format as comma separated string
  //At here reset the DataSourceUpdateMode to Never
  //We can also do this in BindingComplete event handler with BindingCompleteContext = BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate
  myCustomControl.DataBindings[0].DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never;
};
myCustomControl.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

myCustomControl has a method to update/populate the new items for the List property called UpdateList(), we have to set DataSourceUpdateMode to OnPropetyChanged at the very beginning of the method like this:

```
public void UpdateList(){
    if(DataBindings.Count > 0) DataBindings[0].DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    //The remaining code for populating/updating new items goes below
    ....
}
```

And that's all, very clean. Hope this will help someone who will encounter the same situation with me.Thank you!